# How to Authorize Against AD with Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication

I am creating an internal website for my company in which everybody who will access this site is part of AD.

What I am trying to do is, when a user connects to the site, they are automatically authenticated against AD. Depending on what group they are a part of for this particular web app (a number of AD groups), I show them different views of the site.

Currently, I started off with something simple (but what I do not think is correct) in that I have the AD logic in the _Layout.cshtml and, based on the results I get there, I then display the different view for the rest of the page (various partial views). This works, but it doesn't feel right.

I also think I'm going to have an issue in that I want this authentication to carry across the entire site - not just per view but to actually restrict what the person can access and show them only the data associated with them.

Does anybody have any suggestions for the correct way to do this? I have searched for tutorials, but nothing has specifically jumped out at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I am a complete and utter dolt.

This does work with Windows authentication back to AD...

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"DOMAIN\an.ad.group")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

Why didn't it work for me? Turns out I had spelled my group name incorrectly. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Although it states it's *Outdated* it completely relevant for your use. Check out [How To: Use Membership in ASP.NET 2.0 with the Actve Directory Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx#paght000022_usingtheactivedirectorymembershipprovider).

*UPDATE*

`I did run across this, but, I want to avoid the user having to log in. I like the auto nature of the Windows authentication. Can this forms approach be modified to work with Windows authentication?`

Not exactly.  If you do not wish the user to type a username and password then you are required to use [Windows Authentication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-vb) AND they must be using Internet Explorer (at least last time I used Windows Authentication).

Windows Authentication does a significant amount of additional configuration. You will have to allow the users who can log in access to the IIS directories.  I'm pretty sure you cannot use SQL Connection Pooling, so each user will have to have a login to the SQL if you website uses a SQL server.

Comment: I did run across this, but, I want to avoid the user having to log in. I like the auto nature of the Windows authentication. Can this forms approach be modified to work with Windows authentication?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways you can do this is by using Sharepoint. It already has the structure in there to connect with AD. http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/Pages/Try-It.aspx

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to introduce Sharepoint into his ASP.NET MVC 3 app just for authentication......

Comment: I agree with @marc_s. While Sharepoint is used within my organization, I want to learn how to do this outside the context of Sharepoint.

Comment: That is my mistake, when I was reading it, I got the sense he was just looking for suggestions on how to integrate with AD. Always had a good outcome using Sharepoint in this type of environment, so I was just making a suggestion. 

"What I am trying to do is, when a user connects to the site, they are automatically authenticated against AD. Depending on what group they are a part of for this particular web app (a number of AD groups), I show them different views of the site."

^ That paragraph sounded 100% like something I would do in Sharepoint. Easily!